# Django override template static file location

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

If I am overriding the templates for an installed app I put the .html files in `/templates/appname/`. I am wondering where the proper location is to store the static files for those overridden templates would be?

Would I put them in `/common_static/appname`? Else is there a better location or way to override templates all together?

Ex. app is named notifications:

```
├── common_static
│   ├── notifications
│       ├── css
│           ├── styles.css
│       ├── js
│           ├── anim.js


├── templates
│   ├── base.html
│   ├── notifications
│       ├── file1.html
│       ├── file2.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store them wherever you want. There is no 'proper location', however you must:

### Make sure Django recognizes the directory that contains your static template files as a **Template Directory**.

From the Django Docs:

> Django searches for template directories in a number of places,
> depending on your template-loader settings (see “Loader types” below),
> but the most basic way of specifying template directories is by using
> the TEMPLATE_DIRS setting.

To add/change Template Directories, use the [TEMPLATE_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-TEMPLATE_DIRS) tuple in your settings file. For example:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
"/home/html/templates/template.html",
"/home/html/templates/default",
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to store Templates and Statics in Django.
Following are two Architectures which can be used:

***A. The one you mentioned above:***

> /templates - Store all templates of the Project with folder app_name
> to store app specific templates
>
> /static - Store all statics of the
> Project with folder app_name to store app specific templates

- This is use-full in sense that you will **know where all** the templates and static files of your Project are.
- It is also **easier to manage** and has **less chances** of Name conflicting.

***B. Store templates and Statics in Specific Apps:***

> templates - Stores only Project level templates e.g. base.html,
> 404.html etc
>
> app_name>/templates - Store all templates related to that Specific App.
>
> static - Store only Project level statics e.g. favicon.ico etc
>
> app_name/static - Store all statics related to that Specific App.

- This is use-full if you want to **Build standalone Apps**, which can be
  used independently.
- But there are **more chances of name conflicts** in this case so you
  will have to follow some naming convention e.g prefix 'app_name_'
  before template names or some other.

Also, you will have to Add these template and Statics paths to TEMPLATE_DIRS and STATICFILES_DIRS setting in Django e.g.

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (<app_name>/templates,)
STATICFILES_DIRS = (<app_name>/static,)
```

And you will have to run **./manage.py collectstatic** for your statics to work in Production Mode (i.e. DEBUG = False)